# Finding The Obtuse Angle

Tags: trigonometry

I asked a question on physics stackexchange, that I suppose would be more appropriate for the math forum: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/44229/finding-the-obtuse-angle

I'd appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that 48° is the (counterclockwise) angle between the negative $x$ axis and your ray? Then the angle between the positive $x$ axis and your ray is 228° counteclockwise or 132° clockwise.